# Attempting to pass props through render in Vue.js and watch them

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parent-child, state

I'm having trouble passing a prop from a parent down through a created child using CreateElement/render in vue.js and then watching it.

Here is my parent component

```
Vue.component('my-drawing', MyDrawing)

new Vue({
  el: '#drawing',
  mounted() {
    Bus.$on('emitColorSelection', (emitString) => {
      console.log("inside socket.js/my-drawing and emitString is ", emitString);
      this.useColor = emitString;
      console.log('inside socket.js/my-drawing and this.useColor after set is ', this.useColor);
    })

  },
  data() {
    return {
      channel2: null,
      canvases: [],
      useColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
    }
  },
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement(MyDrawing, {
      props: {
        useThisColor: this.useColor
      }
    })
  }
});
```

So you can see here is that I take the value of the emit for some bus and then I pass that to useColor. I would like to then pass this value to my render function as useThisColor.

Here then is the child.

```
<template>
  //my template stuff
</template>

<script>
//stuff
  watch: {
    useThisColor (n, o) {
      console.log("useThisColor watch, ", n, o) // n is the new value, o is the old value.
    }
  } 
//stuff continues
```

So this watch tag doesn't output. I've also tried putting the props in the template to no effect, as well as trying to output it on a `Updated:` tag. I've also attempted to set props in the parent using quotes. Nothing so far has worked and I am a little confused. If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Comment: What are the props for MyDrawing?

Comment: The top level myDrawing parent itself has no props. It gets emitted a Bus as shown, and not shown is that it is emitted changes to the canvases array from a phoenix backend (although that should not affect this problem). EDIT: currently the child my-drawing has no props as it is modifying canvases and emitting over a channel using phoenix. So, the problem right now is passing props through createElement and watching them.

Comment: The MyDrawing component needs to have a prop called `useThisColor`.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/mmQyze?editors=1010

Comment: Bert you have just made my day. Kudos kudos kudos. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I expect the issue here is you simply didn't define the property, `useThisColor`, on the MyDrawing component.

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/mmQyze?editors=1010).